# Cut a character vector into name, numbers and na values in R

Tags: r, regex, vector

I have a character vector that starts with a name, followed by numbers and `NA` values without separators. The `NA` values have length 3 (`na.`) and the numbers can differ in length, depending if they are negative or positive. E.g. `-1.0` has length 4 and `0.7` has length 3. 
 Input:

```
mydata <- c("indigo-1.00.71.21.01.11.12.52.5na.na.1.21.01.01.0na.na.na.na.",
             "lago1.9-0.71.21.01.11.12.52.5na.na.1.21.01.01.0na.na.na.na.")
```

```
mydata 
[1] "indigo-1.00.71.21.01.11.12.52.5na.na.1.21.01.01.0na.na.na.na."
[2] "lago1.9-0.71.21.01.11.12.52.5na.na.1.21.01.01.0na.na.na.na."
```

The solution should be a character vector that looks like this:

```
[1] "indigo" "-1.0" "0.7" "1.2" "1.0" "1.1" "1.1" "2.5" "2.5" "na." "na." "1.2" "1.0" "1.0" "1.0" "na." "na." "na." "na."
[2] "lago" "1.9" "-0.7" "1.2" "1.0" "1.1" "1.1" "2.5" "2.5" "na." "na." "1.2" "1.0" "1.0" "1.0" "na." "na." "na." "na."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `base R`, maybe you can try the solution below by using `regmatches()`, i.e.,

```
regmatches(mydata,gregexpr("[[:alpha:]]+|-?\\d.\\d|na\\.",mydata))
```

such that

```
> regmatches(mydata,gregexpr("[[:alpha:]]+|-?\\d.\\d|na\\.",mydata))
[[1]]
 [1] "indigo" "-1.0"   "0.7"    "1.2"    "1.0"    "1.1"    "1.1"    "2.5"    "2.5"    "na."    "na."    "1.2"    "1.0"   
[14] "1.0"    "1.0"    "na."    "na."    "na."    "na."   

[[2]]
 [1] "lago" "1.9"  "-0.7" "1.2"  "1.0"  "1.1"  "1.1"  "2.5"  "2.5"  "na."  "na."  "1.2"  "1.0"  "1.0"  "1.0"  "na."  "na." 
[18] "na."  "na.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do using `stringr` and some regular expressions:

```r
mydata <- c("indigo-1.00.71.21.01.11.12.52.5na.na.1.21.01.01.0na.na.na.na.",
            "lago1.9-0.71.21.01.11.12.52.5na.na.1.21.01.01.0na.na.na.na.")

library(stringr)
str_extract_all(mydata, "^[[:alpha:]]+|-{0,1}\\d.\\d|na.")
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] "indigo" "-1.0"   "0.7"    "1.2"    "1.0"    "1.1"    "1.1"    "2.5"   
#>  [9] "2.5"    "na."    "na."    "1.2"    "1.0"    "1.0"    "1.0"    "na."   
#> [17] "na."    "na."    "na."   
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] "lago" "1.9"  "-0.7" "1.2"  "1.0"  "1.1"  "1.1"  "2.5"  "2.5"  "na." 
#> [11] "na."  "1.2"  "1.0"  "1.0"  "1.0"  "na."  "na."  "na."  "na."
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note, that the result is a list with elements that contain one character vector for each element in the original vector. The exact form that you stated above is not possible in `R`

Comment: thanks, but the first element in the first list should be ````indigo````, the second element ````-1.0````. in the second list, the first three elements are wrong.

Comment: Maybe `str_extract_all(mydata, "^[[:alpha:]]+|-*[0-9.]{3}|na.")`